# Mysql Selecting same number of records with different filter paramaters

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on project for prizes draw in php and what is required for me is the following, I've 4000 user and the selection should goes as follows:

```
EMP_ID
------
1123
1420
1340
2301
2330
4430
4321
3456
3425
7753
4256
4895
```

as you see I have different number of users; and they ask me in every draw to select 1000 user, but the 1000 should be divided in equals between the employees Ids like selecting 200 row from the employees that start with 1 and other 200 from employees that starts with 2 and so on.

I accomplished this but with multiple selection statements, like select random 200 row from employees which starts with 1 and another SQL for employees which start with 2 and.....; is there any better solution that can accomplish this in one SQL statement?

Comment: Your approach is fine. But see UNION.

Comment: @Strawberry ok thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if any one interested in @strawberry suggestion it would be like this

```
    select x.* from 
((SELECT a.`emp_id` FROM `emp_list` as a WHERE a.`flag` = '0' AND a.`emp_id` LIKE '1%' order by RAND() limit 200)
UNION
(SELECT b.`emp_id` FROM `emp_list` as b WHERE b.`flag` = '0' AND b.`emp_id` LIKE '2%' order by RAND() limit 200)
UNION
(SELECT c.`emp_id` FROM `emp_list` as c WHERE c.`flag` = '0' AND c.`emp_id` LIKE '3%' order by RAND() limit 200)
UNION
(SELECT d.`emp_id` FROM `emp_list` as d WHERE d.`flag` = '0' AND d.`emp_id` LIKE '4%' order by RAND() limit 200)
UNION
(SELECT g.`emp_id` FROM `emp_list` as g WHERE g.`flag` = '0' AND g.`emp_id` LIKE '7%' order by RAND() limit 200)
) as x order by RAND()
```